# No index mapper found for field [...] returning default posting formats

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a custom mapper plugin under elasticsearch version 2.4.0 but I have this warning in the log every time I insert new data

```
no index mapper found for field [....] returning default posting formats
```

I search for this but all I can find is about upgrades issues, nothing like this. Were any ideas wrong? Thanks.